# jekyll SEO - Image is not working, but title and description are working

Tags: image, seo, jekyll

Im using jekyll to host my blog, While sharing my blog links to LinkedIn or somewhere, the Image is not showing, but title and descriptions are working.

Then I checked the source of the page, there Im not able to find og:image

Im using so-simple theme.

### Sample post:

```
title: MySQL With DevOps 2 - Simplified MySQL PITR In One Click
date: 2019-03-03 18:30:00 +0000
description: Find out the Binlog file name, a position from backup and perform PITR
  will take more time. Now its simplified PITR in one click.
categories:
- MySQL
tags:
- mysql
- automation
- rundeck
- backup and recovery
- pitr
- shellscript
image: /assets/MySQL With DevOps 2 - Simplified MySQl PITR In One Click.png
```

Comment: what is the html output of your post? I suppose the problem is the whitespace in the filename. Suggestion: convert whitespace to underscore and see if this helps.

Comment: It's fixed now. Please never mind.